# What is the definition for "equivalent linear programming problems"?

Tags: linear-programming

My question is in the title:

> How can we define exactly when two linear programming problems are equivalent?

I used to see some definition such as "$B$ is equivalent to $A$ if $B$ is solvable, then $A$ is solvable", but it is quite confusing to use this definition to check whether two LP problems are equivalent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without even recalling the definition of L.P. Problem, I'd risk calling them equivalent if the solution set is the same. **Edit:** Having re-read the definition of L.P.Problem, I stand by my risk.

Comment: @GitGud there are many cases the solution set can't be the same, because they are in different spaces. For example, when you need to add some slack variables to a LP to make it into standard form, the solution sets are not the same at all.

Comment: Of course they are. Slack isn't part of the solution.